# How to implement regularized least squares in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, least-squares

I am trying to implement in Matlab the paper Reducing boundary artifacts in image deconvolution available [here](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/papers/deconvolution_boundary_iccp08.pdf).

The problem I am running into is that I don't know how to implement in matlab the regularized least square problem described in the paper.

[image: regularized least square problem]

Can anyone give me some suggestions? Until now I found the lasso function in matlab
but I am not sure this is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Try to formulate it in matrix form like `min(|| X*w - Y || + k*||w||)`, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A=double(A);
[M,N]=size(A);
Dm=eye(M);
Dn=eye(N);
Dxx=diff(Dm,2,1); % 2nd derivative
Dyy=diff(Dn,2,1);
LA=kron(Dxx,Dn)+kron(Dm,Dyy); %Laplacian operator

I=eye(M*N);
A1=zeros(size(A)); 
A1(1:alpha,:)=1;  % alpha in formula (1) and (2) from paper, boundary margin
A1(M-alpha:M,:)=1; 
B1=zeros(size(B));     % B is A' in the formula
B1(1:alpha,:)=1;
B1(M:M+alpha,:)=1;   % B1 is A-A', boundary elements padded as the paper shows

H=[LA;sqrt(lambda)*I(A1,:)];  % consolidate the laplacian operator in the 1st part and the norm in the 2nd part 
y=[zeros(size(LA,1),1);B(B1)]; % convert the original problem to a matrix equation Hx=y
X=reshape(H\y, M,N);
```

Comment: There is an error on the second line after A1 is defined. Could you also explain the code, please?

Comment: I converted the optimization form to a matrix equation. Basically if you are trying to optimize |ax-b|^2+|cx-d|^2, you are equivalently solving [a;c]x = [b;d]. That's how H and y are formed in the code. The boundary subtraction may be revised further (perhaps after better understanding of the paper), but the basic method that handle optimization as a matrix equation form is presented

Comment: Another question: who is Im and In (did you mean Dm and Dn) ?

Comment: @lennon310, this code really needs an explanation – inline, not in a comment.

Comment: @A.Donda Thank you Donda. More comments added within the code.

Comment: @lennon310 I was able to implement something. When you compute the laplacian, shouldn't that include A in the computation? Now I got too small intensities for X.

Comment: @catalaur I thought A is what you are going to solve. You finally select the A that gives you the minimal of that arg, is that correct?

Comment: @lennon310 Yes you are correct. I though that initially I consider A to be my image. This has more to do with my understanding of the paper.

Comment: @lennon310, This is a great solution! Will it work for this as well: http://noodle.cs.huji.ac.il/~danix/epd/index.html How would you do it for very large images (Overcome memory constraints)?

Comment: @lennon310, Could you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016744/creating-filters-laplacian-matrix-and-solving-the-linear-equation-for-image-fil Thank You.