# Creating Filter's Laplacian Matrix and Solving the Linear Equation for Image Filtering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem to solve in order to filter an image.
I created a Linear Equation of the problem which deals with Sparse Matrices.

At first I will show the problem.
First, the Laplacian (Adjacency) matrix of the problem:

[image]

The matrix Dx / Dy is the forward difference operator -> Hence its transpose is the backward difference operator.
The matrix Ax / Ay is diagonal matrix with weights which are function of the gradient of the image (Point wise, namely the value depends only on the gradient on that pixel by itself).
The weights are:
[image]
Where Ix(i) is the horizontal gradient of the input image at the i-th pixel (When you vectorize the input image).

Assuming input Image G -> g = vec(G) = G(:).
I want to find and image U -> u = vec(U) = U(:) s.t.:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How can I build the matrices Dx / Dy / Ax / Ay effectively (They are all sparse)?
2. By setting M = (I + \lambda * {L}_{g}), Is there an optimized way to create M directly?
3. What would be the best way to solve this linear problem in MATLAB? Is there a way to by pass memory limitations (Namely, dealing with large images and still be able to solve it)?
4. Is there an Open Source library to solve it under limited memory resources? Any library with MATLAB API?

Thank You.

Comment: You can use the `sparse` command to build sparse matrices.  If you know the row and column indexes of those non-zero entries as well as what those numbers should be in those non-zero locations, you can easily build this in sparse.  To start with building the matrices, start slowly and make them with `for` loops.  We want to be sure you're getting the matrices correctly.  Once you do that, you can simply apply the \ operator to solve for the inverse and is **very** optimized for sparse matrices.

Comment: As for the Open Source library, \ is pretty much as fast as you'll get it.  There are **iterative** methods, in case \ doesn't work due to memory limitations.  You can take a look at Successive Over-relaxation methods.  Here is some code to get you started: https://github.com/burakbayramli/kod/blob/master/books/Olver/sor.m . `w` is a weight that controls the convergence of the method, which is between `0 < w < 2`.

Comment: @rayryeng, Could you even help me with the first 'loop' step? Thank You.

Comment: Can you give me some more insight on how `Dx` and `Dy` are structured?

Comment: They are the matrix operator which applies forward difference. In MATLAB I think you can get it by `diff(eye(size(inputImage)))`.

Comment: Alright, and `Ax` and `Ay`... The output for each of those entries is essentially the gradient at that point wrt to the `x` and `y` direction, right?  I'm also assuming that `Ax` and `Ay` are also sparse?  I'm pretty sure I can do this without `for` loops then.

Comment: Yes, Ax and Ay are also sparse with values only on their diagonals (Look at the update to clarify that which I added). Thank You.

Comment: `Ax` and `Ay` would then be `rows*cols x rows*cols` long, but the definition of `Dx` and `Dy` would make the matrix `rows x cols` long.  This is the intended result, correct?

Comment: Ax size is (rows*cols x rows*cols) and it has values along its diagonal only. Dx and Dy aren't the gradient image, they are the operators to do so, hence they are size of (rows*cols x rows*cols) as well. I was wrong with the definition above - Dx = diff(eye(rows * cols))).

Comment: Alright, I'll assume it's of the same size for now.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments, let's answer each question in a synopsis and go from there:

1. I will answer that question below using `sparse` and other related functions
2. Using (1), we can definitely build `M` in an optimized way.
3. Simply put, the \ operator is the best thing to use when solving an inverse.  MathWorks have spent so much time trying to optimize it, and it pretty much uses LAPACK and BLAS under the hood, that you would be insane not to use it.  The only time you wouldn't be able to use it is answered in (4).
4. There are some MATLAB scripts that can handle solving the matrix **iteratively**, like the Successive Overrelaxation technique, but you should only use those if your run out of memory (i.e. if \ doesn't give you an answer).  With the sparse representation of the matrices, this shouldn't (hopefully) happen, so let's avoid using those functions for now.

Going back to your question, we can produce a sparse representation of `L_g` very nicely.  Given the definition of `Dx` and `Dy`, we can use the **sparse** version of the `eye` command called `speye`.  Therefore, `Dx` and `Dy` can be calculated by `Dx = diff(speye(size(inputImage)));`  As an example, this is what would be produced if you tried doing this on a 7 x 5 image.

```
>> diff(speye(7,5))

ans =

(1,1)       -1
(1,2)        1
(2,2)       -1
(2,3)        1
(3,3)       -1
(3,4)        1
(4,4)       -1
(4,5)        1
(5,5)       -1
```

As you can see, we are referencing only non-zero entries.  Row 1, column 1 has a coefficient of -1, row 1, column 2 has a coefficient of 1 and so on.  As for your `Ax` and `Ay`, that's also very easy to do.  We have a diagonal matrix and we can set each of the entries manually.  All we would do is specify a set of row indices, column indices, and what the values are at each point.  Therefore, we can do that by:

```
inputImage = im2double(inputImage); %//Important
rows = 1 : numel(inputImage); %// Assuming a 2D matrix
cols = rows; % // Row and column indices are the same
valuesDx = exp(-(gradX(rows).^2 / 2*sigma*sigma ));
valuesDy = exp(-(gradY(rows).^2 / 2*sigma*sigma ));
```

The reason for the first call is because we want to make sure that the pixels are in double precision, as finding the inverse in MATLAB requires that you do this.  It also ensures we don't overflow the type as we are normalizing the intensities between 0 and 1.  You may have to adjust your standard deviation to reflect this.  Now we just need to construct our `Ax` and `Ay` matrices, and let's put it together with `Dx` and `Dy`:

```
numberElements = numel(inputImage);
Ax = sparse(rows, cols, valuesDx, numberElements, numberElements);
Ay = sparse(rows, cols, valuesDy, numberElements, numberElements);
identity = speye(numberElements, numberElements); 
Dx = diff(identity);
Dy = Dx.'; %// Transpose
```

The reason why I'm transposing `Dx` to get `Dy` is because the difference operator in the vertical direction should simply be the transpose (makes sense to me).  These should all be **sparse** representations of each of the matrices you want.  Matrix operations can also be performed on sparse matrices, including multiplication and the inverse.  As such:

```
Lg = Dx.' * Ax * Dx + Dy.' * Ay * Dy;
```

You can now solve for `u` via:

```
u = (identity + lambda*Lg) \ g;
```

This assumes that `g` is structured with your pixels in your image in **column-major** format.  The way I sampled the pixels to build `Ax` and `Ay` naturally follows this.  As such, do `g = inputImage(:);`, assuming that we have converted to double and normalized between 0 and 1.

When you finally solve for `u`, you can reshape it back to an image by doing:

```
u = reshape(u, size(inputImage, 1), size(inputImage, 2));
```

`u` may also be sparse, so if you want the original image back, cast it using `full()`:

```
u = full(u);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Drazick Do you require any further assistance?

Comment: @Drazick - ... so what happened buddy?  Did this help?

Comment: Hi, Somehow I missed it. Let me try it in the next coming weeks. Thank You!!! I will +1 it for now.

Comment: By the way, any libraries to solve this kind of Eigen Vectors problems under limiting memory resources (Actually, even 8GB would be limiting for large 6000x4000 pixels images, so any practical solver needs to be able to do it with limited resources).